# Laravel Livewire: How to pass data in preConfirm SweetAlert 2

Tags: jquery, laravel-livewire, sweetalert2

In the project, we used laravel livewire. In index, there's a button where when the user clicked the button it will open a modal.

Where the modal is for the confirmation before deleting the records, I used javascript/jquery to pass the id in the hidden input field but now I'm having a trouble to pass the id in my component

Question: How do I pass the data inside of preConfirm method of sweetalert 2?

**Javascript**

```
if ( $('form#delete-data-form').length > 0 ) {
    $('div').on('submit', 'form#delete-data-form', function(e){
        var id       = $('input[name="module_id"]').val();
        var module_name = getMonth(id);
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "you want to delete all the data of "+module_name+"?",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
            cancelButtonText : 'Cancel',
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
            preConfirm: function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    var name = @this.call('deleteData',id).then(() => {
                        Swal.fire('Loading complete');
                    });
                }
            },
        });
       
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    })
}
```